# Pair autoscaled app & db servers together with consul

Tags: java, consul, service-discovery

Currently, I have two GCE auto-scaled groups of servers, bootstrapped by the chef. 1st - redis servers (`db`), 2nd - java servers (`app`).

Any `app` server can talk to any `db` server. Every `db` need to be served by `app` server, and there should be no situation when one `app` server has connections to two separate `db` servers.

So, I need to figure out if I can connect newly created app-server with newly-created DB-server (all in the same network), using consul.

All in all, I need to automatically pair new up-scaled servers, by adding appropriate `db` server IP or hostname to the command, that starting java on the `app` server.

I'm very new to service discovery and stuff, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer after edit:

So if I understand you correctly, any *new* app server can talk to any *new* redis server, but once they picked a db server to talk to, they should stick with that server.

I can see a few ways to achieve that with consul:

1. Map each app server 1-to-1 to a redis server and expose each server as a different service in consul with domain names like: `app1.service.consul`, `redis1.service.consul`. The drawback here is that you can not scale your app servers independently from your redis servers.
2. Use [Redis Sentinel](https://redis.io/topics/sentinel) and let it abstract the sharding of the data for you and the just expose it under one domain name in consul: `redis.service.consul`

I would suggest to look into the second option, since it allows you to scale your app and db servers independently.

#### Old answer:

It sounds like you have two services in your network: An `app` service and a `db` service. You would then typically make consul serve as the DNS server for both of them.

This can be achieved by creating a service file for each of them.
On the server where your app is running you would create a service file in `/usr/local/etc/consul.d/my_app.json`:

```
{
  "service": {
    "name": "my_app",
    "port": 1234
  }
}
```

Where you replace `port` with the port your app is listening on.
You then need to reload consul with `consul reload`. You can check that the changes where applied correctly by running `consul monitor`.

Your app should now be reachable from `my_app.service.consul` on your internal network.

You can check this by issuing a DNS query with `dig my_app.service.consul`. This should return the IP address of the app server in the ANSWER section of the DNS response.

You then have to repeat these steps on your database server where you need to create another service file for the database with the appropriate port and service name.

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion, comrade. Actually, both `app` and `db` servers are in separate auto-scaling groups, so I need a new `db` server to pass some kind of `lock` status (I suppose..) for a new `app` server to find out that it's free to work with, and connect to it. Am I right?

Comment: @Blasterdick It sounds like your setup is more comlicated than what you described in your question. If you update your question with an exact description of your problem, I can probably give a better anwer.

Comment: Yes, that helps. But there is still something missing: What type of database are you using? Is your data sharded? I.e. can any app server talk to any db server or does a specific app server need to talk to a specific db server?

Comment: Sorry for that. I use redis as `db`, in-memory only. Yup, any `app` server can talk to any `db` server.

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion, comrade. The "architecture feature" of the app is that it can't work with redis queue if some another app already working with it. And such kind of situations is possible if I would use Sentinel, I suppose. So, I would better use cunsul (if you will be so kind as to help me with it).

Comment: Also, I can't be tied up with app1<-->redis1 pairs by numbers, as if one of them would become unavailable, I should start a new one and make it work with an old one "widow". So they should be able to also work in pairs like app1<-->redis3.

Comment: Honestly, it sounds like your architecture choices might not be the best. Can you update your question with your exact usage pattern of redis? It sounds like you are only using it as a cache and not to store valuable data. Is that right?

Comment: Redis is used as the message queue. Also, I'm not the developer of this app (and I'm not the developer at all), so I can't make decisions concerning its architecture.

Comment: Excuse me, if my answer was impolite, I didn't mean that. English isn't my native, and sometimes it's pretty poor.

Comment: No worries, you were not impolite at all. I am just a bit confused about your use case. It sounds like you are trying to use Redis in a very unconventional way. Typically there is just 1 message queue in an app and it is not tied to specific app servers. Couldn't you just get away with 1 beefy Redis server in the beginning?

Comment: Nope, if I'll do that, java would fail to work with keys in db, as they a named by time, and blablabla (it's difficult for me to explain). So, I need to use consul way with mapping redis to java nodes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130621/discussion-between-rkrzr-and-blasterdick).